# Showing $|\exp(tA)| \leq K$ if all eigenvalues have real part negative or zero (and if zero real part, simple eigenvalue)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wish to show that if all eigenvalues have real part negative or zero and if those eigenvalues with zero real part are simple, there exists a constant $K>0$ such that $|\exp(tA)| \leq K$, $(0<t<\infty)$, and hence every solution of $y' = Ay$ is bounded on $(0 \leq t < \infty)$.

We can write our matrix $A$ as $A = PBP^{-1}$ and since all eigenvalues are simple, $B$ is diagonal so $A^n = PB^nP^{-1}$. If $B$ is nilpotent then our sum has finite number of terms and stops at the $n-1$ term.

EDIT:

Comment: You mean the norm of the matrix? It is a usual convention that $|A|$ denotes the determinant of the matrix $A$.

Comment: Hi @LutzL ..of course ah sorry. I've made an edit. Could you please see it?

Comment: This seems now wrong. You get from the differential equation and the Wronski relation that $\det(\exp(tA))=\exp(t\,{\rm trace}(A))$, so that this interpretation is trivial. I think your task is really for the norm $\|\exp(tA)\|$, probably the spectral norm.

Comment: @LutzL Here is a photo of the exericse: https://i.imgur.com/dUby5kn.png By spectral norm, we have to talk about the maximum norm $\sqrt{A^H A}$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html But here we don't know which eigenvalue will the be maximum. I don't think we have enough information for that

Comment: The spectral norm is $\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^HA)}$, the Frobenius norm is $\sqrt{trace(A^HA)}$, you probably have to use the first one.

Comment: where does the inequality $det(A)+det(B) \leq det(A+B)$ come from. Isn't it false when $A=I$ and $B=-I$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, that is false. I've removed it.

Comment: I just posted my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I will focus on showing that $\Vert e^{At} \Vert$ is bounded where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the standard *operator norm*,

$\Vert A \Vert = \sup \{\Vert Ax \Vert, \; \Vert x \Vert = 1 \} = \inf \{C \mid \Vert Ax \Vert \le C \Vert x \Vert, \; \forall x \}, \tag 0$

where $\Vert x \Vert$ is the standard Hermitian norm for vectors $x \in \Bbb C^n$, that is, $\Vert x \Vert$ is derived from the Hermitian inner product

$\langle y, z \rangle = \displaystyle \sum_1^n \bar y_i z_i, y = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n)^T \in \Bbb C^n, \; \text{etc,} \tag{0.1}$

by

$\Vert x \Vert^2 = \langle x, x \rangle =  \displaystyle \sum_1^n \bar x_i x_i. \tag{0.2}$

We resort to extending the normal real Euclidean inner product on $\Bbb R^n$ to the Heritian product (0.1) to facilitate addressing and handling situations in which some of the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-real complex numbers.

We want to show that

$\forall t \in \Bbb R, \; 0 \le t < \infty, \Vert e^{At} \Vert < K \tag 1$

for some $0 < K \in \Bbb R$.

We know that $A$ may be cast into Jordan canonical form by a similarity transformation

$A \to PAP^{-1} \tag 2$

for some non-singular matrix $P$; we thus first deal with the case of $A$ a Jordan matrix; indeed, we will first address the situation when $A$ is a single *Jordan block*, that is, a matrix of the form

$A = \lambda I_m + N, \tag 3$

here $I_m$ is the $m \times m$ identity matrix, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $N$ is the $m \times m$ nilpotent matrix consisting of $m - 1$ $1$s on the superdiagonal and zeroes everywhere else.  Since $I_m$ commutes with $N_m$, that is,

$I_m N_m = N_m = N_m I_m, \tag 4$

it follows that

$e^{At} = e^{(\lambda I_m + N_m)t} = e^{\lambda I_m t + N_m t} = e^{\lambda I_m t} e^{N_m t}; \tag 5$

now it is both well-known and easy to see from the matrix power series of $\exp$ that

$e^{\lambda I_m t} = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{(\lambda I_m t)^k}{k!} = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{\lambda^k t^k I_m }{k!} = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{\lambda^k t^k}{k!} I_m = e^{\lambda t} I_m; \tag 6$

also, since the nilpotent matrix $N$ satisfies

$N^m = 0, \tag 7$

we have

$e^{N_m t} = \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} \dfrac{N_m^k t^k}{k!}, \tag 8$

which is an $m \times m$ matrix whose entries are polynomials in $t$ of degree at most $m - 1$; it follows from (5), (6) and (8) that $e^{At}$ takes the form

$e^{At} =  e^{\lambda t} I_m \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} \dfrac{N_m^k t^k}{k!} = e^{\lambda t}  \sum_0^{m - 1} \dfrac{N_m^k t^k}{k!}, \tag 9$

and if

$\lambda = \sigma + i \omega, \; \sigma < 0, \tag{10}$

we may further decompose $e^{At}$ as

$e^{At} = e^{i\omega t} e^{\sigma t} \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} \dfrac{N_m^k t^k}{k!}, \tag{11}$

whence

$\Vert e^{At} \Vert = \left \Vert  e^{i\omega t} e^{\sigma t} \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} \dfrac{N_m^k t^k}{k!} \right \Vert = \vert e^{i\omega t} \vert \left \Vert e^{\sigma t} \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} \dfrac{N_m^k t^k}{k!} \right \Vert = \left \Vert e^{\sigma t} \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} \dfrac{N_m^k t^k}{k!} \right \Vert. \tag{12}$

Now it is well-known that for $\sigma < 0$ the expression on the right of (12), being dominated by the exponential $e^{\sigma t}$, eventually decreases to $0$ as $t \to \infty$:

$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} \Vert e^{At} \Vert = \lim_{t \to \infty} \left \Vert e^{\sigma t} \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} \dfrac{N_m^k t^k}{k!} \right \Vert = 0; \tag{13}$

since

$\displaystyle  \Vert e^{At} \Vert = \left \Vert e^{\sigma t} \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} \dfrac{N_m^k t^k}{k!} \right \Vert. \tag{14}$

is continuous as a function of $t$, it is bounded on any compact interval $[0, \tau]$; by choosing $\tau$ sufficiently large we may, in the light of the limit (13), assume $\Vert e^{At} \Vert < \epsilon$, $0 < \epsilon \in \Bbb R$, for $t \ge \tau$; therefore (14) is bounded by some $0 < K \in \Bbb R$ for all $t \in [0, \infty)$.  We note that in the case $\sigma = 0$, we have $m = 1$ by our hypotheses on the matrix $A$, and the Jordan block reduces to $e^{i\omega t}$, which is manifestly bounded; indeed, as long as the block size is $1$, the block reduces to $e^{(\sigma + i \omega)t}$ with $\sigma \le 0$ and is thus easily seen to be bounded in norm.

The preceding discussion shows that $e^{At}$ is bounded for any Jordan block (3) of $A$ as long as $\sigma = \Re(\lambda) \le 0$; if $A$ is comprised of multiple Jordan blocks, then there is a bound for each and hence, since the number of Jordan blocks is finite, a bound over all the Jordan blocks of $A$ is obtained by taking the greatest such bound.

The preceding discussion covers the situation when $A$ is in Jordan form; it result may be extended to any $A$ by inverting the similarity transformation (2), an operation which preserves the boundedness of $\Vert e^{At} \Vert$ (though it may alter a *particular* bound) since $P$ does not depend upon $t$.  We conclude that, in all specified/required cases, there is some $K > 0$ with

$\Vert e^{At} \Vert < K, \; t \in [0, \infty). \tag{15}$

And we are done.

Comment: This is very detailed thank you so much. I believe I understand it, but i'll come back with comments when I find things I am confused about.

Comment: @Nalt:  thank you.  Looking forward to hearing from you.  Cheers!