# Stability of $y = \cos(2t)$ for the ode $y'' + 4y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to examine the stability of the solution $\phi = \cos(2t)$ of the ode $y'' + 4y = 0$.

I know the general solution of this ode is $y = c_1 \cos(2t) + c_2 \sin(2t)$. So to examine the stability of my solution, I need to see if other solutions stay close to it starting at $t = 0$. It'll be asymptotically stable if other solutions converge to it.

So, when $t = 0$, $\phi(0) = \cos(0) = 1$. and $\phi'(0) = -\sin(0) =0$. But.. how do I pick $y(t)$ so that $y(0)$ starts out close to $1$ and $y'(0)$ is close to $0$? Then what?

Well, $y(t) = 1$ when $t = 0$ and when $t = 0$, $y'(0) = 1$. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that :

$$-1 \leq \sin(2t) \leq 1 \quad \text{and} \quad -1 \leq \cos(2t) \leq 1$$

That means that your solution will be bounded, by let's say, some $m \in \mathbb R$ and $M \in \mathbb R$, such that :

$$m \leq y(t) \leq M$$

This automatically tells us that the system is stable, since its solutions do not diverge for any values of $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb R$ arbitrary constants.

But, note that the limits $\lim_{t\to  \infty} \sin(2t)$ and $\lim_{t\to  \infty} \cos(2t)$ do not exists, which means that your solutions will not get arbitrary close to each other.

Thus, the given ODE solution is simply stable.

For a more formal definition (which proves our conclusions above) recall that :

> **Definition :** A solution of an ODE is stable if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0 $ when if $\hat{y}(t)$ satisfies the ODE, it is :
>   $$\|\hat{y}(t) - y(t_0) \| \leq \delta \implies  \|\hat{y}(t) - y(t)\| \leq \varepsilon \; \forall t \geq t_0$$

Comment: Thanks Rebellos! Your answer and Prof. Israel's really helped me to understand!

Comment: @Nalt Glad I could help ! You may also use the "vote up" arrows (buttons) to reward users for answering something that helps you !

Answer (score 3):

Since all solutions are periodic, this is stable but not asymptotically stable: solutions that start close stay close, but do not converge to your solution.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer. I am little new at learning about stability so: This is stable because it is periodic. The reasoning being that all solutions stay within a range of the solution $\cos(2t)$, between $-1$ and $1$. Is this it?