# Prove that $x(t)$ is bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

In this problem, I tried the following:
First I show that 
$$x(t) = e^{tA}x_0 + \int\limits_0^t e^{(t-s)A}f(s)ds$$
Then I take the norm for both sides 
$$\|x(t)\|\leq Ke^{-\alpha t}\|x_0\|+\left\|\int\limits_0^t e^{(t-s)A}f(s)ds\right\|$$
I have used Meiss’s Lemma ($\|e^{tA}\|\leq K e^{-\alpha t}\|$ for some $K>0$, $\alpha >0$).

Could you please help me in what is remaining, and if there is any mistake. Thanks.

Comment: You just bring the norm inside the integral and you conclude

Comment: And see [Norm bound on exponential matrix with eigenvalue negative real part](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374432/norm-bound-on-exponential-matrix-with-eigenvalue-negative-real-part-proof) to bound the matrix norm.

Comment: It is not enough to bring the norm inside the integral, I think you have to take A into consideration.

Comment: Ok ... My problem is: when we bring the norm inside what will happen to the integral as $t \to \infty$

Comment: Could you please check my comment @Federico

Comment: @Ahmed here is the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the already given hints,
$$
\begin{split}
\|x(t)\|
&\leq Ke^{-\alpha t} \|x_0\| + \left\|\int_0^t e^{(t-s)A}f(s)\,ds\right\| \\
&\leq Ke^{-\alpha t} \|x_0\| + \int_0^t \bigl\|e^{(t-s)A}f(s)\bigr\|\,ds \\
&\leq Ke^{-\alpha t} \|x_0\| + \int_0^t \bigl\|e^{(t-s)A}\bigr\|\|f(s)\|\,ds \\
&\leq Ke^{-\alpha t} \|x_0\| + K\|f\|_\infty \int_0^t e^{\alpha(s-t)}\,ds \\
&= Ke^{-\alpha t} \|x_0\| + K\|f\|_\infty \frac{1-e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha} \\
&\leq Ke^{-\alpha t} \|x_0\| + \frac{K\|f\|_\infty}\alpha .
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Should we eliminate also $e^{-\alpha t}$ as $t\to\infty$

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not taking any limits here. I only used $1-e^{-\alpha t}\leq 1$.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean in the first term? Well then yes you can eliminate $Ke^{-\alpha t}\|x_0\|\leq K\|x_0\|$ because $e^{-\alpha t}\leq 1$. But you can also keep it because it provides a slightly better inequality