# Bound on the state of a stable LTI system under disturbances

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider a linear time-invariant (LTI) system
$$
\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bw(t); \quad x(0)=x_0
$$
where $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the state, $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the initial state, and $w(t)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is the disturbance. The matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is Hurwitz, i.e., $\text{eig}(A)\subset\mathbb{C}_{<0}$, and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. Note that
$$
x(t) = \exp(At) x_0 + \int_0^t \exp(A\tau)Bw(t-\tau)d\tau
$$
where $\exp(\cdot)$ is the matrix exponential function.

Since $A$ is Hurwitz, there exists $\lambda>0$ such that $\|\exp(At)\|\leq e^{-\lambda t}$. Thus,
$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
\|x(t)\| &\leq & e^{-\lambda t} \|x_0\| + \|\int_0^t \exp(A\tau)Bw(t-\tau)d\tau\| \\
&\leq & e^{-\lambda t} \|x_0\| + \int_0^t \|\exp(A\tau)Bw(t-\tau)\| d\tau \\
&\leq & e^{-\lambda t} \|x_0\| + \int_0^t \|\exp(A\tau)B\| d\tau . \|w_{[0,t]}\|_\infty.
\end{array}
$$
This is from Chapter 2 of the book "Feedback Control Theory" by Doyle, Francis, and Tannenbaum.

**Question 1:** What is the value of $\int_0^t \|\exp(A\tau)B\| d\tau$?

**Question 2:** Can it be characterized in terms of $\mathcal{H}_2$/$\mathcal{H}_\infty$ gains?

**Question 3:** Does it have a relation with the controllability gramian $\int_0^\infty \exp(A\tau)BB^T\exp(A^T \tau) d\tau$?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for in Q1 and Q3? Are you looking for some intuition?

Comment: I think Q1 is simple, we can compute the bound. In Q3, I want to see how the controllability gramian is related to the term mentioned in Q1. If it is related, then it means that if the system can be steered with low energy input, then the bound will be large; and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1.** This depends on the values for $A$ and $B$ but it is difficult to compute in general. A very conservative upper bound can be computed using the fact that $\|\exp(A\tau)B\|\le \|\exp(A\tau)\|\|B\|$ and that $\|\exp(A\tau)\|\le \exp(\|A\|\tau)$. In this case, we have that

$$\int_0^t \|\exp(A\tau)B\| d\tau\le\dfrac{\exp(\|A\|t)-1}{\|A\|}\|B\|.$$

Note, however, that this bound grows without bound as $t$ increases while the integral converges to a finite value. A better bound can be obtained using the matrix measure (or logarithmic norm)

$$\mu(A)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{||I+hA||-1}{h}$$

which verifies

$$\|\exp(A\tau)\|\le\exp(\mu(A)\tau),\ \tau\ge0$$
and yields

$$\int_0^t \|\exp(A\tau)B\| d\tau\le\dfrac{\exp(\mu(A)t)-1}{\mu(A)}\|B\|.$$

**Question 2.** No. This is more related to the concept of input-to-state stability and the $L_\infty$-induced norm.

**Question 3.** We have that

$$\int_0^t \|\exp(A\tau)B\| d\tau=\int_0^t \lambda_{max}[B^T\exp(A^T\tau)\exp(A\tau)B]^{1/2} d\tau.$$

However, the integral does not commute with the eigenvalue operator and the square root. So, there is no direct relation with the controllability Gramian.

Comment: Thanks. For you approach of Question 1, it is better to use the bound on $\|\exp(A\tau)\|\leq M e^{-\alpha \tau}$. See> https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1374432/442550